# Estimating VECM with restricted cointegrating vectors in R

Tags: r

I want to estimate a VECM with four variables, e.g.: `data <- c(v1, v2, v3, v4)`.

I want to impose the cointegrating vectors: `v1-v2, v1-v3, v1-v4` or in matrix form:

```
beta = [ 1 -1 0  0
         1  0 -1 0
         1  0 0  -1]
```

I have tried using `lineVar` in the `tsDyn` package, but I am having trouble specifying the beta constraint using the beta option in `lineVar`. For example:

```
vecm.eg <- lineVar(data, lag=1, r=3, model='VECM', estim='ML', beta=????????).
```

Please advise on how I should specify beta. I tried setting `beta=matrix.above`, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you tried googling "VECM CRAN" to see what packages come up? Have you tried out the available examples in those help pages? What are you having trouble finding? Do you know that a statistical method already exists for your particular problem?

Comment: I have tried the lineVar in tsDyn package, but I am having trouble specifying the beta constraint using the beta option in lineVar. for example, vecm.eg <- lineVar(data, lag=1, r=3, model='VECM', estim='ML', beta=????????). please advice on how I should specify beta. I tried setting beta=matrix.above, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: That is very important information. Please edit your original question to include that detail. Show what you tried and what error messages you got along the way. That will make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: What is the dim(data) in your case? Is that a matrix? How many rows/columns?

Comment: dim(data) = T x 4, where T is the number of time series observations.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/tsdyn/source/browse/trunk/tsDyn/R/lineVar.R?r=328), I see that with VECM uses the beta for

```
ECTminus1 <- Xminus1 %*% c(1,-beta)
```

where

```
Xminus1 <- embed(data,lag+2)[,(ncol(data)+1):(ncol(data)+ncol(data))]
```

so in your case, it looks like `beta=c(1,1,1)` would work. But I admit I don't have a deep understanding how this should work.

Comment: unfortunately the suggested solution did not work, and i get the following error: 

> vm <- lineVar(data, lag=1, r=3, model='VECM', estim='ML', beta=c(1,1,1))
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
> traceback()
2: `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("ECT1", "ECT2", "ECT3", "Intercept", 
"a -1", "b -1", "c -1", "d -1"))
1: lineVar(data, lag = 1, r = 3, model = "VECM", estim = "ML", beta = c(1, 
1, 1))